# Rails - How to put a confirmation popup on a f.submit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to have a confirmation popup on a `<% f.submit %>` call on a new object form.  Is there a way to do this without javascript?

Comment: POst your code, post your errors. What have you tried? Do you have any mockups or examples to show us what you want? (I'm trying to help you write a better question since you're new).

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You want `<%= f.submit :confirm => 'Your confirm message' %>`. Just FYI, this is just the short hand for the javascript call.

Edit:
As stated in other answers, the new way to have a popup confirm is:

```
<%= f.submit 'Save', data: { confirm: 'Your confirm message' } %>
```

Comment: [it should](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-button_tag). Unless you have javascript turned off. If js is not enabled there is no way of doing what you want. If it is, you could try `<%= f.submit :onclick => "return confirm('your message here')" %>`

Comment: `<%= f.submit :onclick => "return confirm('your message here')" %>` Works.  I'm having a very difficult time understand the technology stack of the app I'm working on.  Thanks.

Comment: But where does the button title go? I'm trying this, but it doesn't work: `<%= f.submit "Some title", :confirm => 'Your confirm message' %>`

Comment: try `<%= f.submit "title", data: { confirm: "confirm msg" } %>`

Comment: The reasons those probably don't work (and `onclick` does) is because you are missing jquery/ujs.

Answer (score 12):

The  correct way is to use:

```
= f.submit "Save", data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to submit this form?" }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Rails 7 with Hotwire Turbo, you have to do it on the form itself. Not on the `f.submit` button. Simply add this to your `form_with`:

```
:data => { turbo: true, turbo_confirm: "Are you Sure?" }
```

Here a bigger example with more context:

```
<%= form_with(:model  => @timesheet,
              :url    => timesheet_path(@orga.name),
              :method => "POST",
              :class  => 'form-horizontal',
              :data   => { turbo: true, turbo_confirm: "Are you Sure?" } ) do |f| %>

    ... SOME FORM INPUT ...

    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit :class => "btn btn-primary", :value => t('time_sheets.submit') %>
    </div>

<% end %>
```