# Add confirm: "Sure?" to f.submit

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, form-submit, form-for

I have a form with a `submit_tag`.

I want both to set the content value and have a js popup confirming the intent.

I've tried [the suggestion in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15771582/rails-how-to-put-a-confirmation-popup-on-a-f-submit/15771639#comment31865377_15771639) and [what the docs describe](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-submit_tag).

Neither of the below invoke the confirmation dialog, but it does for a `link_to` tag. What am I doing wrong?

```
f.submit "Do this", data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'}  
f.submit "Do this", confirm: 'Are you sure?'
f.submit confirm: 'Are you sure?'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add this `onsubmit` function to your form helper

```
<%= form_for(...  , html: {:onsubmit => "return confirm('Are you sure?');" }) do |f| %>
```

If you have `jQuery` and want to do it un-obstructively, you can do inside of document ready

```
$('#my-form').submit(function() {
  return confirm('Are you sure?');
})
```

Comment: Wow, I've been looking for hours but only on the `submit_tag`. Thank, you! (Btw, cannot vote it up bc of low reputation.) Do you by any chance have any doc reference?

Comment: This is just javascript, and not rails. Google for javascript form submit callback and you will get enough reference :)

Comment: Good answer, but forget about document.ready. Just put it at the bottom.

Comment: @pguardiario, I have mentioned about `document.ready`, in my answer(just above the code)

Comment: @santosh, right, I'm saying don't do that. Don't use document.ready just put the js at the bottom.