# Confirm dialog not working in rails from

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am having large rails form when submit button is clicked the There should be js confirmation dialog box but in my case it is not i cant understand why ??

```
<div class="body-unit">
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <h1>Fill up your academic details</h1>
    <%= form_for @academic, url: user_dashboard_academic_creator_path , method: :post do |f| %>
     <% if @academic.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@academic.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this candidate from being saved:</h2>
          <ul>
          <% @academic.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
          <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
       <% end %>
       <p>
               <%= f.label :tenth_roll %><br>
               <%= f.number_field :tenth_roll %>
       </p>
       <p>
               <%= f.label :tenth_board  %><br/>
               <%= f.text_field :tenth_board %>
       </p>
       <p>
               <%= f.label :tenth_year_pass %><br/>
               <%= f.text_field :tenth_year_pass %>
       </p>
       <p>
               <%= f.label :tenth_marks_percent  %><br/>
               <%= f.number_field :tenth_marks_percent %>
       </p>
       <p>
               <%= f.label :hs_roll %><br>
               <%= f.number_field :hs_roll %>
       </p>
       <p>
               <%= f.label :hs_board  %><br/>
               <%= f.text_field :hs_board %>
       </p>
       <p>
               <%= f.label :hs_year_pass %><br/>
               <%= f.text_field :hs_year_pass %>
       </p>
       <p>
               <%= f.label :hs_marks_percent  %><br/>
               <%= f.number_field :hs_marks_percent %>
       </p>
       <p>
               <%= f.label "Stream" %>
               <%= select("academic", "subject_streams_id", SubjectStream.all.collect {|c| [c.subject_stream, c.id]}) %>

       </p>
       <p> <h3>12th/Higher Secondary Subjects</h3><br>
         Subject 1 - 8 compulsory </p>
       <p>
               <%= f.label "Subject 1"   %><br>
               <%= f.text_field :sub1 , class: "sub-input" %><br>
               <%= f.label "Subject 1 Marks"   %><br>
               <%= f.number_field :sub1_marks , class: "sub-input" %><br>
       </p>
       <p>
               <%= f.label "Subject 2"   %><br>
               <%= f.text_field :sub2 , class: "sub-input" %><br>
               <%= f.label "Subject 2 Marks"   %><br>
               <%= f.number_field :sub2_marks , class: "sub-input" %><br>
       </p>
       </div>
       <div id="tabs-3">
       <p>
               <%= f.label "Subject 3"   %><br>
               <%= f.text_field :sub3 , class: "sub-input" %><br>
               <%= f.label "Subject 3 Marks"   %><br>
               <%= f.number_field :sub3_marks , class: "sub-input" %><br>
       </p>
       <p>
               <%= f.label "Subject 4"   %><br>
               <%= f.text_field :sub4 , class: "sub-input" %><br>
               <%= f.label "Subject 4 Marks"   %><br>
               <%= f.number_field :sub4_marks , class: "sub-input" %><br>
       </p>
       <p>
               <%= f.label "Subject 5"   %><br>
               <%= f.text_field :sub5 , class: "sub-input" %><br>
               <%= f.label "Subject 5 Marks"   %><br>
               <%= f.number_field :sub5_marks , class: "sub-input" %><br>
       </p>
       <p>
               <%= f.label "Subject 6"   %><br>
               <%= f.text_field :sub6 , class: "sub-input" %><br>
               <%= f.label "Subject 6 Marks"   %><br>
               <%= f.number_field :sub6_marks , class: "sub-input" %><br>
       </p>
       <p>
               <%= f.label "Subject 7"   %><br>
               <%= f.text_field :sub7 , class: "sub-input" %><br>
               <%= f.label "Subject 7 Marks"   %><br>
               <%= f.number_field :sub7_marks , class: "sub-input" %><br>
       </p>
       <p>
               <%= f.label "Subject 8"   %><br>
               <%= f.text_field :sub8 , class: "sub-input" %><br>
               <%= f.label "Subject 8 Marks"   %><br>
               <%= f.number_field :sub8_marks , class: "sub-input" %><br>
       </p>
       <p>
               <%= f.label "Subject 9"   %><br>
               <%= f.text_field :sub9 , class: "sub-input" %><br>
               <%= f.label "Subject 9 Marks"   %><br>
               <%= f.number_field :sub9_marks , class: "sub-input" %><br>
       </p>
       <p>
               <%= f.label "Subject 10"   %><br>
               <%= f.text_field :sub10 , class: "sub-input" %><br>
               <%= f.label "Subject 10 Marks"   %><br>
               <%= f.number_field :sub10_marks , class: "sub-input" %><br>
       </p>

       <p><%= f.submit "Submit", data: { confirm: "Are you sure data once submitted cat be changed?"}, class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg"  %></p>
     <% end %>
   </div>
</div>
```

please explain me why is it not working ? I have another page with where i have a form and its working there.
you can check out the live here although it needs to login [heroku link](https://warm-refuge-6265.herokuapp.com)

Comment: What happens when you try this `<%= f.submit "Submit", confirm: "Are you sure data once submitted cat be changed?", class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg" %>`?

Comment: its just gets submitted

Comment: You mean no confirmation message?

Comment: yes just pain submit..

Comment: It should work unless your javascript is turned off.If so try `<%= f.submit "Submit",:onclick => "return confirm("Are you sure data once submitted cant be changed?)", class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg" %>`.

Comment: But where is the problem there is no error in my code either?

Comment: Yes,your code is fine.Do you have `javascript` installed and it is working in your machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the **[API](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/submit_tag)**

> confirm: 'question?' - If present the unobtrusive JavaScript drivers
>   will provide a prompt with the question specified. If the user
>   accepts, the form is processed normally, otherwise no action is taken

As i said,your code should work fine unless your `Javascript` is turned off.If so try the below

```
<%= f.submit "Submit",:onclick => "return confirm('Are you sure data once submitted cant be changed?')", class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg" %>
```

This should work.

**[Source(refer the comments)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15771582/rails-how-to-put-a-confirmation-popup-on-a-f-submit)**