# Why is return needed for onclick confirmation button for submit_tag

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Ruby on Rails [submit_tag](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/submit_tag) to submit an HTML form on my site. Here's my code for the submit tag:

```
= submit_tag "Increase Limits", { onclick: "return confirm('are you sure?')", class: "btn btn-danger"}
```

This is inside my `.haml` page. My understanding is that the `confirm()` call is just a wrapper over Javascript's `window.confirm()`. Why is the `return` necessary? According to this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15771582/rails-how-to-put-a-confirmation-popup-on-a-f-submit) I should just be able to use `confirm()` without the return keyword?

Inside my `rails-root/app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file I have the line `//= require rails-ujs` if that's relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an `onclick` method returns `false` it causes the event's default action to be prevented. The default action of clicking on a submit button is to submit the form.

If you don't use `return`, the method doesn't return a value, so the submit action will be executed regardless of how the user answers the confirmation dialog.

Comment: Yes that, and this basically returns the return value of [`confirm()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm) function: `true` or `false`. You can block/continue the submit. Also you could use Rails [`data: {confirm: 'are you sure?'}`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-submit_tag).

Comment: gotcha. I created a string in my controller like `@confirmation_msg = .........` and in my view I have `onclick: "return confirm(#{@confirmation_msg})"` however this doesn't show the message and instead the confirmation popup is blank. Do you know why that is?

Comment: I don't know RoR, so I can't help with that syntax.